# what is the benefit of the taint model over node selector

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning Kubernetes, and and faced a conceptual question, what is the benefit of new taint model over the simple node selector.

Documentation talks about a usecase where a group of devs might have exclusive right for a set of pods by a taint like `dedicated=groupA:NoSchedule`. But I thought we can do the same thing by a simple nodeSelector.

To be more specific, what is the role of the effect on this taint. Why not simply a label like the rest of the Kubernetes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A node selector affects a single pod template, asking the scheduler to place it on a set of nodes. A NoSchedule taint affects all pods asking the scheduler to block all pods from being scheduled there.

A node selector is useful when the pod needs something from the node. For example, requesting a node that has a GPU. A node taint is useful when the node needs to be reserved for special workloads. For example, a node that should only be running pods that will use the GPU (so the GPU node isn't filled with pods that aren't using it).

Sometimes they are useful together as in the example above, too. You want the node to only have pods that use the GPU, and you want the pod that needs a GPU to be scheduled to a GPU node. In that case you may want to taint the node with `dedicated=gpu:NoSchedule` and add both a taint toleration and node selector to the pod template.

Comment: I think in your last example, the only purpose of the *selector* might be to force . a pod to select a GPU node which also, for example, had a selectable feature other than GPU, such as an SSD , or a DMZ node label.  Otherwise, the toleration alone would be sufficient for the scheduler to land that pod on one of the GPU nodes.

Comment: @jayunit100 Is that really true? The toleration says this pod _can_ be (i.e., tolerates being) scheduled on a GPU node, but does *not* say it _must_ be scheduled there. For that you do need affinity, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a clear explanation: https://deploy.live/blog/visual-guide-to-node-selectors-taints-and-tolerations/. I believe we can say that the selector and label of a pod are used to select a node. If a pod does not define a matching label, it can be scheduled on any node, but the node may not be suitable if it has specific resources running. On the other hand, taint and toleration are used by nodes to allow pods. A node will not allow any pod unless you specify its toleration.

Comment: I like his comment, "for predictable, reliable scheduling, I recommend always combine nodeSelector and toleration. This way an intention to schedule a pod on a specific kind of node is very clearly defined, whilst nodes are protected from accidental scheduling of generic workloads that can run elsewhere."